# capture target link on iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, mouseclick-event

Ok, thank you first of all his attention. I have three iframes in 3 different html documents. Organized in this way:

In iframemain.html I have:

```
<iframe src="iframeparent.html" width="100%" height="600">
</iframe>
```

In iframeparent.html I have:

```
<iframe src="iframeson.html" width="90%" height="350" name="_parent">
</iframe>
```

In iframeson.html I have:

```
<iframe src="http://anywebsite.com/samplepage.html" width="80%" height="300">
</iframe>
```

I did this because **http://anywebsite.com/samplepage.html** links are loaded into main window (iframemain.html), and not what I want, I wish I could capture the target and load the content iframeparent.html without afect to iframemain.html

I clarify that I have no control over the content of: http://anywebsite.com/samplepage.html, but it is annoying that your links loaded into the main window, so I would like all of those links are loaded in the same iframe or much in the iframeparent.html

Is this possible with Javascript or Jquery?. Thanks for your answers.

Comment: Not on the client due to same origin policy. You can use a proxy on the server

Comment: please could you explain more? thank you very much

Comment: Search SO for JavaScript proxy

Answer (score 0):

See if I have understood this correctly

You want to frame a page http://anywebsite.com/samplepage.html on iframemain.

That page has a bunch of links with target="_parent" or worse, "_top"

You want the page you have framed to not target iframemain but to have all links stay in that frame.

If the links target _parent, then your solution is correct. If they target _top, you would need to use a proxy on the server. It would break if they change the way they target links (using javascript or base target for example) but the idea is that you have

```
<iframe src="yourproxy.php?url=http://anywebsite.com/samplepage.html" width="80%" height="300"></iframe>
```

and in there, replace all `_top` and/or `_parent` with `_self`

But show some examples of the links (you can change the URL to protect your client) so we can help better